# Check boxes overlap in scrollable table with sticky table head

Tags: material-ui

[image: normal][image: checkbox overlapped]I am creating a scrollable table with fixed table header and checkboxes. The table worked fine(no overlap of table head and body) without the checkbox. With the checkboxes, all rows scrolls just fine except that checkbox in table body would overlap with checkbox (or show up) in table head.

I tried setting backgrounds to white but won't work.

***Issue Demo***: https://codesandbox.io/s/vm6l0p1vly

```
      <div
        style={{
          height: "500px",
          width: "100%",
          overflow: "auto",
          borderStyle: "solid",
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: "lightGray"
        }}
      >
        <Table>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell
                padding="checkbox"
                style={{ position: "sticky", top: 0, backgroundColor: "white" }}
              >
                <Checkbox />
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell
                style={{ position: "sticky", top: 0, backgroundColor: "white" }}
              >
                id
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell
                style={{ position: "sticky", top: 0, backgroundColor: "white" }}
              >
                name
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {data.map(row => (
              <TableRow key={row.id} hover>
                <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                  <Checkbox />
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>{row.id}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{row.name}</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </div>
```

I expect the checkboxes to not overlap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have enough points to comment, but the answer is to set the z-index: 1 for the header containing the checkbox.

Comment: That worked. Dam, didn't think about the stack order of elements. Many thanks!

Comment: Nice!  I've been on that for hours.  Thanks

Comment: Man, thank you. How did you come up with this answer? I wonder why it is not needed for text but it is for checkboxes.